# syntax with variable needed for value pair

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax

I need little help.

How can I insert 2 variables (instead of *190* and *680*) into the following statement:

```
 $("#Y").css( { transformOrigin: '190px 680px' } );
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the css string from the variables.

```
var x-offset = 190;
var y-offset = 680;

$("#Y").css( { transformOrigin: x-offset + 'px ' + y-offset + 'px' } );
```

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot the second + in the middle! :-)